# Why can't I call ask with MonadReader constraint

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

I am trying to call `ask` in a `do` notation block with a `MonadReader` constraint but am getting an error about rigid types. As far as I can tell, `ask` is defined for all `MonadReader`s ?

```
bar :: MonadReader r m => m r
bar = do
  i <- ask
  return i
```

This returns the

> ```
> • Couldn't match type ‘m’ with ‘ReaderT r m0’
>   ‘m’ is a rigid type variable bound by
>     the type signature for:
>       bar :: forall r (m :: * -> *). MonadReader r m => m r
>     at mem.hs:50:8
>   Expected type: m r
>     Actual type: ReaderT r m0 r
> • In a stmt of a 'do' block: i <- ask
>   In the expression:
>     do { i <- ask;
>          return i }
>   In an equation for ‘bar’:
>       bar
>         = do { i <- ask;
>                return i }
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems like you have `ask` imported from `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` but `MonadReader` imported from `Control.Monad.Reader`. The `ask` function from `Control.Monad.Trans.Reader` is monomorphic, and it only works with `ReaderT`. Just import `Control.Monad.Reader` on its own—it re-exports `ReaderT`, but it provides generalized versions of `ask`, `local`, and `reader`.

Comment: One caveat: `local` from `C.M.T.R` allows the environment type to change, while the one from `C.M.R` does not.